# Can custom console application be executed in Azure (PowerShell) Runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Can I use my own/custom console application in Azure Runbook (PowerShell or any other)?

When I try to run my own console application (after [retrieving it from Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50531989/850848)), it fails.

---

When I try to execute it simply by:

```
.\myapp.exe
```

I get:

> Program 'myapp.exe' failed to run: The operation was canceled by the user

---

When I use `System.Diagnostics.Process`:

```
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo.FileName = $path
$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $False
$process.Start()
```

I get a more meaningful error:

> Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact 
>   your system administrator"

---

Is there any settings in Azure Automation, I can toggle, to allow executing custom applications? Or is it simply not possible in the restricted Runbook environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out! Unfortunately your ask of running .exe inside an Azure Automation runbook is currently not supported. And yes, you can go with Azure Web Job(s). One other customer has recently reached out with similar ask and solved their issue by leveraging Azure Web Job(s). For clarification, you may refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/298e7e29-0828-4101-8e89-72ee15745a39) MSDN thread. Hope this helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I'm aware that I can use a WebJob. It's that the RunBook is more lightweight (and not need a Web site).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately , it is not supported by Azure Automation Runbook for now.[Here is a feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/31957750-can-we-execute-exe-or-bat-files-inside-runbook) replied by Automation PG team , there is no update on it.

Comment: Hi @Martin , if my answer is helpful, pls mark me : )  Hope you have a nice day !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lets see if anyone comes with a better answer or at least with an official and up to date source.

Answer (score 2):

You can however

1. Run console app as Azure WebJob on App Service and call it remotely via SCM endpoint or,
2. Compile console application as PowerShell cmdlet

   ```csharp
   using System.Management.Automation; 

   namespace MyApp
   {
     [Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Send, "RunApplication")]
     public class RunApplicationCommand : Cmdlet
     {
       protected override void ProcessRecord()
       {
         // App Code goes here
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   - Attach compiled DLL to PowerShell module
   - Deploy PowerShell modle to Automation account using Modules > Import
   - Call cmdlet from runbook

Comment: What do you mean by *"Compile console application as PowerShell cmdlet"* – It actually looks like you suggest that I rewrite my console application in PowerShell, right?

Comment: No I don't, I gave you sample of the code. Just copy paste your application code into this sample. Compile it in visual studio which will return .DLL files that can be attached as powershell module. This means you have the console app still written in C# that can be called directly from powershell on Azure Automation service.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it's a C# code. -- Anyway, my application is not in C#, not even .NET. -- It's a useful answer anyway (but not for me).

Comment: Though note that you can use a regular .NET (C# or any other) assembly in PowerShell in Runbook. So actually, there's no need for turning a .NET code into cmdlet.

Comment: This means you should go for option 1. So run this .exe as webjob.